# Which gas cartridges (fuel) can I use for Bluegaz Mobile Stove?

Tags: stoves, fuel, canister-stoves

I have a [Bluegaz Mobile Stove](https://bluegaz.se/produkt/bluegaz-mobile-stove/) (product ID 470001) which I purchased in Sweden. The [manufacturer's website](https://bluegaz.se/produkt/bluegaz-mobile-stove/) doesn't list the right type of gas cartridge, however some [other website](https://www.gardenstore.se/gasolkok-bluegaz) seems to suggest it is a "Bluegaz BG250".

Unfortunately, I can't find any online shop that sells "Bluegaz BG250".

Does anybody know of a place where I could purchase "Bluegaz BG250" or an alternative gas cartridges that would work?

If it matters, I'm based in London, UK.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the Bluegaz Mobile Stove looks almost exactly like the [Campingaz Camp'Bistro 2](https://www.campingaz.com/uk/p-27302-campbistro-2-stove.aspx) which takes [Campingaz CP250](https://www.campingaz.com/uk/p-27007-cp250.aspx) gas cartridges. So I took the punt and bought some CP250s. I'm pleased to say that they work and fit perfectly, so I believe that the Campingaz CP250 is exactly the same as the Bluegaz BG250.

---

In case it helps, please fine some pictures below

The Bluegaz Mobile Stove

[image: Bluegaz Mobile Stove]

and a picture that is (probably) the BG250:

[image: possibly Bluegaz BG250]

Compare that to the Campingaz Camp'Bistro 2

[image: Campingaz Camp'Bistro 2]

with its Campingaz CP250:

[image: Campingaz CP250]

Comment: Most of these cartridges are generic despite the branding, so if it fits one, it will likely fit most of the other similar models. The one thing you should watch out for is the mix of fuels in the cartridge - they can have different ratios of butane:propane, and a burner designed for say 80:20 won't burn efficiently on a 70:30 or _vice versa_

Comment: Thanks @bob1, any idea how I could find out what ratio my stove/gas is?

Comment: It should be written on the cartridge. However, looking around at similar 250 canisters, it seems that no-one provides information on the components of the gas in this sort of canister. This likely indicates that all the similar canisters are the same sort of gas mix. So this issue might only be for the more complex hiking stoves like MSR.  Note - the wrong mix will still burn, it just won't burn as cleanly or as hot as the proper mix.

Comment: Thanks @bob1. Unfortunately, I don't have the original cartridge anymore. I bought it in Sweden and after the holiday took a flight home (UK) taking the stove but leaving the cartridge -- assuming it'd be very easy to find :).